# How to resolve volley.NoConnectionError in Android?

Tags: android, rest, https, slim

I'm having trouble with getting Android App to connect to a https server using the HttpsUrlConnection object. Any one help me to resolve this issue.

I am creating a BKS file like this.

```
keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -file "C:\path_to_file\app_cert.crt" -alias lrl -keystore "keystore.bks" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.46.jar" -storetype BKS -storepass "password"
```

In my main file:

```
    public class Application extends android.app.Application {


    private static Application mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private static char[] KEYSTORE_PASSWORD = "password".toCharArray();

    private PreferenceManager pref;

    public static final String TAG = Application.class.getSimpleName();
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mInstance = this;
      super.onCreate();
    }


    public static synchronized Application getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        FontUtils.clean();
        super.onTerminate();
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            //mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext(), new HurlStack(null, newSslSocketFactory()));
            mRequestQueue.start();
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                    new LruBitmapCache());
        }
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }


    public PreferenceManager getPrefManager() {
        if (pref == null) {
            pref = new PreferenceManager(this);
        }

        return pref;
    }



    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }


    private static SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
        try {
            KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS"); //PKCS7
            InputStream in = Application.getInstance().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore);

            try {
                trusted.load(in, KEYSTORE_PASSWORD);
            } finally {
                in.close();
            }

            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(trusted);

            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

                @Override
                public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "ARG =" + arg0 + " == arg1" + arg1);
                    return true;
                }
            });
            context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
            SSLSocketFactory sf = context.getSocketFactory();
            return sf;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    } 

}
```

My Network Handler File

```
public class NetworkRequestHandler {


private String TAG = NetworkRequestHandler.class.getSimpleName();
private static NetworkRequestHandler mInstance = null;
private  ServerResponseListener mListener=null;

public static NetworkRequestHandler getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new NetworkRequestHandler();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public void setListener(ServerResponseListener listener)
{
    mListener= listener;
}



public void sendNetworkRequest(String endPoint,final Map<String, String> params,final String responseType, int requestType) {
    try {
        String url= Config.BASE_URL+endPoint;

        System.out.println("URL =="+url);

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(requestType,url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Logger.d("","response " + response);
                if(mListener != null) {
                    mListener.success(response, responseType);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                error.printStackTrace();

                if(mListener != null) {

                    mListener.failure();
                }
            }
        })
        {
            /**
             * Passing some request headers
             * */
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return headers;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getParams() {
                return params;
            }

        };
        strReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        Application.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, responseType);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.d(TAG, "Problem while doing HTTP Request");
        if(mListener != null) {
            mListener.failure();
        }
    }
}
```

I got the following exception

```
    06-10 04:38:41.597 5936-5936/com.aetasapp W/System.err: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer
06-10 04:38:41.605 5936-5936/com.aetasapp W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:151)
06-10 04:38:41.605 5936-5936/com.aetasapp W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
06-10 04:38:41.605 5936-5936/com.aetasapp W/System.err: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer
06-10 04:38:41.613 5936-5936/com.aetasapp W/System.err:     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
06-10 04:38:41.613 5936-5936/com.aetasapp W/System.err:     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:398)
06-10 04:38:41.613 5936-5936/com.aetasapp W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:209)
06-10 04:38:41.613 5936-5936/com.aetasapp W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:478)
06-10 04:38:41.613 5936-5936/com.aetasapp W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:442)
06-10 04:38:41.613 5936-5936/com.aetasapp W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
06-10 04:38:41.620 5936-5936/com.aetasapp W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
06-10 04:38:41.620 5936-5936/com.aetasapp W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
06-10 04:38:41.620 5936-5936/com.aetasapp W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
06-10 04:38:41.620 5936-5936/com.aetasapp W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:281)
06-10 04:38:41.620 5936-5936/com.aetasapp W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:240)
06-10 04:38:41.620 5936-5936/com.aetasapp W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:210)
06-10 04:38:41.620 5936-5936/com.aetasapp W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:106)
06-10 04:38:41.620 5936-5936/com.aetasapp W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
06-10 04:38:41.620 5936-5936/com.aetasapp W/System.err:     ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Test the code with another server. Perhaps there was an authentication error somewhere when connecting with the server. That is my first deduction from the logcat you posted.